# Is it okay to switch tire sizes on my rims from 205 55 R16 to 205 60 R16? will they fit?

Tags: tires, vw, wheels

I have a 2021 VW Golf comfortline the stock tire size is 205 55 R16 all seasons i have a set of winter tires i want to switch into the stock 16” rim that came with the car but the tires i want to switch are a different size 205 60 R16 Winters would they still fit? Is it okay to up the tire size? Whats the respectable range that’s safe to go up or down in tire size

Answer (score 1):

Yes that will be ok.

There are many questions about tire sizes on here with links to tire size calculators, which will tell you about % change speedo error etc

As it is a small change it will have lttle effect - slightly softer over bumps, slightly more flex in the sidewall but you might not notice depending how you drive.